# mysql + xmpp server +test loading - did I reach any physical limit?

Tags: java, mysql, load, tsung, tigase

during load tests (simulating users connecting to the server), for the first 1750 seconds there is a mean transaction / second rate of about 300-400, with peak of about 700 tr/sec. These transaction are making some use of server's underlying mysql database, at a rate of about 5 - 10 queries per transaction. There are not any joins, views or more complicated stuff, but straightforward queries, db being indexed accordingly too, innoDB storage engine. The machine has plenty of RAM and CPU power, and monitoring reveals even at SQL Exceptions, the machine has way more than 50% free CPU/RAM resources. Db entries are of the order of magnitude 10^5, and still, I have about 20-30 of these exceptions:

```
    2012-06-07 01:56:55  XGateRoster.<init>()                SEVERE:   Error getting data list for: +39128516@xmpp.xgate.com.hk/offline/XGate/PhoneBook; method took 14672 ms, thread: 878
tigase.db.TigaseDBException: Error getting data list for: +39128516@xmpp.xgate.com.hk/offline/XGate/PhoneBook; method took 14672 ms, thread: 878
    at tigase.db.jdbc.JDBCRepository.getDataList(JDBCRepository.java:482)
    at tigase.db.UserRepositoryMDImpl.getDataList(UserRepositoryMDImpl.java:225)
    at tigase.xmpp.RepositoryAccess.getDataList(RepositoryAccess.java:393)
    at tigase.xmpp.RepositoryAccess.getOfflineDataList(RepositoryAccess.java:458)
    at tigase.xmpp.impl.XGateRoster.<init>(XGateRoster.java:94)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor50.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at tigase.xmpp.impl.DynamicRoster.init_settings(DynamicRoster.java:294)
    at tigase.xmpp.impl.DynamicRoster.getDynamicRosters(DynamicRoster.java:214)
    at tigase.xmpp.impl.DynamicRoster.getBuddiesList(DynamicRoster.java:137)
    at tigase.xmpp.impl.DynamicRoster.addBuddies(DynamicRoster.java:83)
    at tigase.xmpp.impl.Presence.broadcastProbe(Presence.java:685)
    at tigase.xmpp.impl.Presence.processOutInitial(Presence.java:1518)
    at tigase.xmpp.impl.Presence.process(Presence.java:914)
    at tigase.server.xmppsession.SessionManager$ProcessorWorkerThread.process(SessionManager.java:2135)
    at tigase.util.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:132)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Query execution was interrupted
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1055)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3491)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1936)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2060)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2542)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1734)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1885)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.CallableStatement.executeQuery(CallableStatement.java:894)
    at tigase.db.jdbc.JDBCRepository.getUserUID(JDBCRepository.java:668)
    at tigase.db.jdbc.JDBCRepository.getUserUID(JDBCRepository.java:1553)
    at tigase.db.jdbc.JDBCRepository.getNodeNID(JDBCRepository.java:1539)
    at tigase.db.jdbc.JDBCRepository.getDataList(JDBCRepository.java:436)
    at tigase.db.UserRepositoryMDImpl.getDataList(UserRepositoryMDImpl.java:225)
    at tigase.xmpp.RepositoryAccess.getDataList(RepositoryAccess.java:393)
    at tigase.xmpp.RepositoryAccess.getOfflineDataList(RepositoryAccess.java:458)
    at tigase.xmpp.impl.XGateRoster.<init>(XGateRoster.java:94)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor50.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at tigase.xmpp.impl.DynamicRoster.init_settings(DynamicRoster.java:294)
    at tigase.xmpp.impl.DynamicRoster.getDynamicRosters(DynamicRoster.java:214)
    at tigase.xmpp.impl.DynamicRoster.getBuddiesList(DynamicRoster.java:137)
    at tigase.xmpp.impl.DynamicRoster.addBuddies(DynamicRoster.java:83)
    at tigase.xmpp.impl.Presence.broadcastProbe(Presence.java:685)
    at tigase.xmpp.impl.Presence.processOutInitial(Presence.java:1518)
    at tigase.xmpp.impl.Presence.process(Presence.java:914)
    at tigase.server.xmppsession.SessionManager$ProcessorWorkerThread.process(SessionManager.java:2135)
    at tigase.util.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:132)
2012-06-07 01:57:14  XGateRoster.<init>()                SEVERE:   Error getting data list for: +3919522@xmpp.xgate.com.hk/offline/XGate/PhoneBook; method took 0 ms, thread: 835
tigase.db.TigaseDBException: Error getting data list for: +3919522@xmpp.xgate.com.hk/offline/XGate/PhoneBook; method took 0 ms, thread: 835
    at tigase.db.jdbc.JDBCRepository.getDataList(JDBCRepository.java:482)
    at tigase.db.UserRepositoryMDImpl.getDataList(UserRepositoryMDImpl.java:225)
    at tigase.xmpp.RepositoryAccess.getDataList(RepositoryAccess.java:393)
    at tigase.xmpp.RepositoryAccess.getOfflineDataList(RepositoryAccess.java:458)
    at tigase.xmpp.impl.XGateRoster.<init>(XGateRoster.java:94)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor50.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at tigase.xmpp.impl.DynamicRoster.init_settings(DynamicRoster.java:294)
    at tigase.xmpp.impl.DynamicRoster.getDynamicRosters(DynamicRoster.java:214)
    at tigase.xmpp.impl.DynamicRoster.setItemExtraData(DynamicRoster.java:361)
    at tigase.xmpp.impl.JabberIqRoster.dynamicSetRequest(JabberIqRoster.java:169)
    at tigase.xmpp.impl.JabberIqRoster.process(JabberIqRoster.java:329)
    at tigase.server.xmppsession.SessionManager$ProcessorWorkerThread.process(SessionManager.java:2135)
    at tigase.util.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:132)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Query execution was interrupted
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1055)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3491)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1936)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2060)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2542)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1734)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1885)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.CallableStatement.executeQuery(CallableStatement.java:894)
    at tigase.db.jdbc.JDBCRepository.getUserUID(JDBCRepository.java:668)
    at tigase.db.jdbc.JDBCRepository.getUserUID(JDBCRepository.java:1553)
    at tigase.db.jdbc.JDBCRepository.getNodeNID(JDBCRepository.java:1539)
    at tigase.db.jdbc.JDBCRepository.getDataList(JDBCRepository.java:436)
    at tigase.db.UserRepositoryMDImpl.getDataList(UserRepositoryMDImpl.java:225)
    at tigase.xmpp.RepositoryAccess.getDataList(RepositoryAccess.java:393)
    at tigase.xmpp.RepositoryAccess.getOfflineDataList(RepositoryAccess.java:458)
    at tigase.xmpp.impl.XGateRoster.<init>(XGateRoster.java:94)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor50.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at tigase.xmpp.impl.DynamicRoster.init_settings(DynamicRoster.java:294)
    at tigase.xmpp.impl.DynamicRoster.getDynamicRosters(DynamicRoster.java:214)
    at tigase.xmpp.impl.DynamicRoster.setItemExtraData(DynamicRoster.java:361)
    at tigase.xmpp.impl.JabberIqRoster.dynamicSetRequest(JabberIqRoster.java:169)
    at tigase.xmpp.impl.JabberIqRoster.process(JabberIqRoster.java:329)
    at tigase.server.xmppsession.SessionManager$ProcessorWorkerThread.process(SessionManager.java:2135)
    at tigase.util.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:132)
```

I believe the time measurements to be correct as I have double checked them. Why do I get such exceptions ? why is it that sometimes the measured execution time is fairly low (even 0 ms = instant exception throw) ?

Mysql slow logs reveal (just one big issue ?):

```
root@XMPP:/var/log/mysql# egrep "# Query_time: [1-9]+?\..*" /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log.1
# Query_time: 27.826251  Lock_time: 0.000077 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 2
# Query_time: 2.038984  Lock_time: 0.000272 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
# Query_time: 2.040937  Lock_time: 0.000298 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
# Query_time: 2.039785  Lock_time: 0.000347 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
# Query_time: 2.040286  Lock_time: 0.000242 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
# Query_time: 2.039634  Lock_time: 0.000048 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 1
# Query_time: 2.039647  Lock_time: 0.000043 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 1
# Query_time: 2.039711  Lock_time: 0.000059 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 1
# Query_time: 1.103542  Lock_time: 0.000078 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
# Query_time: 1.104395  Lock_time: 0.000053 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 1
# Query_time: 1.103512  Lock_time: 0.000201 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
# Query_time: 1.103431  Lock_time: 0.000038 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 1
# Query_time: 2.375416  Lock_time: 0.000205 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
# Query_time: 2.911025  Lock_time: 0.000039 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 1
# Query_time: 2.083049  Lock_time: 0.000047 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 1
# Query_time: 2.081169  Lock_time: 0.000036 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 1
# Query_time: 2.649307  Lock_time: 0.000233 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
# Query_time: 2.082557  Lock_time: 0.000062 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 1
# Query_time: 3.129848  Lock_time: 0.000124 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 1
# Query_time: 3.158479  Lock_time: 0.000083 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
# Query_time: 3.412682  Lock_time: 0.000194 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
# Query_time: 2.900394  Lock_time: 0.000073 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
# Query_time: 3.414437  Lock_time: 0.000068 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 1
# Query_time: 2.900706  Lock_time: 0.000202 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
# Query_time: 3.195506  Lock_time: 0.000198 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
# Query_time: 2.901220  Lock_time: 0.000323 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
# Query_time: 1.278411  Lock_time: 0.000204 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
# Query_time: 1.284154  Lock_time: 0.000198 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
# Query_time: 1.205004  Lock_time: 0.000342 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
# Query_time: 1.204605  Lock_time: 0.000338 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
# Query_time: 1.205250  Lock_time: 0.000131 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
# Query_time: 1.274901  Lock_time: 0.000059 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 1
# Query_time: 1.285315  Lock_time: 0.000099 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 1
# Query_time: 3.303273  Lock_time: 0.000060 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 1
# Query_time: 3.468223  Lock_time: 0.000041 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 1
# Query_time: 3.461232  Lock_time: 0.000053 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 1
# Query_time: 3.460767  Lock_time: 0.000399 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
# Query_time: 2.758039  Lock_time: 0.000309 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
# Query_time: 3.462436  Lock_time: 0.000049 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 1
# Query_time: 2.757907  Lock_time: 0.000276 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
# Query_time: 4.063776  Lock_time: 0.000183 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
# Query_time: 2.012213  Lock_time: 0.000335 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
# Query_time: 2.232263  Lock_time: 0.000270 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
# Query_time: 2.831812  Lock_time: 0.000052 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 1
# Query_time: 2.832423  Lock_time: 0.000074 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 1
# Query_time: 2.232429  Lock_time: 0.000270 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
# Query_time: 2.832328  Lock_time: 0.000053 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 1
# Query_time: 2.231343  Lock_time: 0.000213 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
# Query_time: 4.234587  Lock_time: 0.000047 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 1
# Query_time: 4.458741  Lock_time: 0.000180 Rows_sent: 50  Rows_examined: 50
# Query_time: 5.739855  Lock_time: 0.000199 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
# Query_time: 5.726863  Lock_time: 0.000289 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
# Query_time: 5.742442  Lock_time: 0.000052 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 1
# Query_time: 5.726623  Lock_time: 0.000048 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 1
# Query_time: 5.727539  Lock_time: 0.000234 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
# Query_time: 5.726928  Lock_time: 0.000222 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
# Query_time: 1.165082  Lock_time: 0.000208 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
# Query_time: 1.161232  Lock_time: 0.000046 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 1
# Query_time: 2.583766  Lock_time: 0.000249 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
# Query_time: 3.011636  Lock_time: 0.000227 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
# Query_time: 2.510544  Lock_time: 0.000227 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
# Query_time: 1.921829  Lock_time: 0.000091 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
# Query_time: 1.920549  Lock_time: 0.000315 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
# Query_time: 1.922647  Lock_time: 0.000239 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
# Query_time: 2.377067  Lock_time: 0.000208 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
# Query_time: 2.511974  Lock_time: 0.000070 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 1
# Query_time: 1.360768  Lock_time: 0.000051 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 1
# Query_time: 1.378182  Lock_time: 0.000104 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 1
# Query_time: 1.806293  Lock_time: 0.000100 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 1
# Query_time: 1.378549  Lock_time: 0.000056 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 1
# Query_time: 1.378903  Lock_time: 0.000088 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 1
# Query_time: 1.879465  Lock_time: 0.000212 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
# Query_time: 2.020542  Lock_time: 0.000054 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 1
# Query_time: 2.019749  Lock_time: 0.000493 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
# Query_time: 2.036685  Lock_time: 0.000303 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
# Query_time: 2.019717  Lock_time: 0.000197 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
# Query_time: 1.963536  Lock_time: 0.000161 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
# Query_time: 2.019353  Lock_time: 0.000129 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
# Query_time: 2.019624  Lock_time: 0.000128 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
# Query_time: 1.820161  Lock_time: 0.000051 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 1
# Query_time: 2.255717  Lock_time: 0.000167 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
# Query_time: 2.413679  Lock_time: 0.000247 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
# Query_time: 2.402931  Lock_time: 0.000148 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
# Query_time: 2.255956  Lock_time: 0.000189 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
# Query_time: 2.353527  Lock_time: 0.000195 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
# Query_time: 2.402936  Lock_time: 0.000204 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
# Query_time: 2.255460  Lock_time: 0.000234 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
# Query_time: 1.169004  Lock_time: 0.000135 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
# Query_time: 2.576578  Lock_time: 0.000039 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 1
# Query_time: 2.578367  Lock_time: 0.000139 Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 3
# Query_time: 2.154770  Lock_time: 0.000209 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
# Query_time: 2.327091  Lock_time: 0.000123 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 1
# Query_time: 2.154538  Lock_time: 0.000209 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
# Query_time: 1.674249  Lock_time: 0.000430 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
# Query_time: 2.913024  Lock_time: 0.000076 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 1
# Query_time: 1.674312  Lock_time: 0.000435 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
# Query_time: 1.992658  Lock_time: 0.000354 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
# Query_time: 1.756505  Lock_time: 0.000247 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
# Query_time: 1.978150  Lock_time: 0.000208 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
# Query_time: 1.979560  Lock_time: 0.000210 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
# Query_time: 1.416010  Lock_time: 0.000458 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
etc...
```

I have tried changing the database jdbc driver, and I have made sure no such bugs are documented in the mysql version I am currently using.

Thank you all for your input!